# Electric for above ground pool

Tags: electrical, pool

I just bought an above ground 24'x52" pool like the one in the link below. Right now the area I am planning on placing it does not have electric close by so I am looking for an easy way to run electric to it for the pump and filter.  Could I simply do a good extension cord or do I need to run some wire underground from the panel?

[https://www.amazon.com/Summer-Waves-Ground-Swimming-Accessory/dp/B01FN4I27U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FN4I27U)

Comment: First off -- is this intended to be a *permanent* pool, or a *temporary* one?

Comment: I think we are going to keep it up year round but we are still debating the pros/cons of each

Comment: Is there an installation manual for the pool you bought that you can post online?